# resultado javascript para metodo na controller parametrizado

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

Estou tentando enviar o resultado de um WebAPI que é consumido via javascript na página para um método na controller que irá fazer uma persistência com esses dados

este é o javascript

```js
$('#CodigoCep').blur(function() {
        var cep = $('#CodigoCep').val();
        
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:13943/cep/" + cep,
                function (data) {
                    $('#Logradouro').val(data.logradouro);
                    $('#Bairro').val(data.bairro);
                    $('#Cidade').val(data.cidade);
                    $('#Estado').val(data.estado);
                })
            .fail(function () {
                $('#Logradouro').val('');
                $('#Bairro').val('');
                $('#Cidade').val('');
                $('#Estado').val('');
            });
    });
```

esse é o método na controller:

```
[HttpPost]
private void CadastraCep(string modelo)
{            
   ... persistir modelo
}
```

como pegar o resultado do primeiro ajax e mandar para esse método ?

Comment: Você quer pegar o resultado desse get e fazer um post pra sua controller? é isso?

Comment: Você quer mandar o valor do `data` recebido pelo post na url?

Answer (score 0):

Você criará nova chamada passando o parâmetro `data`
Veja o exemplo abaixo.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Neste caso, você precisará preferencialmente que este `data` seja um objeto JSON, e no controller você irá manipular este objeto Json.

Neste link tem alguns exemplos. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/